# Search on indexed property mongodb returns no result after laravel upgrade

Tags: laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

Recently i upgraded Laravel from 5.5 to 6. Now when i execute the query below, it returns no result where on 5.5 it did. I am using the JensSegers mongodb package. Asset_id is indexed

This my method.

```
public function show($id)
{
    return response()->json(Asset::where('asset_id', $id)->get());
}
```

My collection looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b28b21a943ee732820286be"
    },
    "asset_id": {
        "$oid": "5b28b202943ee732820282f3"
    },
    "parent_asset_id": {
        "$oid": "5b28b21a943ee732820286bd"
    },
    "updated_by": 1,
    "updated_at": {
        "$date": "2019-08-12T22:12:10.000Z"
    },
    "created_by": 1,
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2018-06-19T07:34:50.000Z"
    },
    "document_ids": [
        "5b28b2c9943ee73282029a35",
        "5b28b2c9943ee73282029a37",
        "5b28b2ca943ee73282029a39",
        "5b28b2ca943ee73282029a3b",
        "5b28b2ca943ee73282029a3d",
        "5b28b2cb943ee73282029a3f"
    ],
    "workOrderAssets": [
        "5b28b203943ee73282028313:1",
        "5b28b209943ee732820283fd:1",
        "5b28b203943ee7328202830f:1",
        "5b28b203943ee7328202830d:1",
        "5b28b203943ee7328202830b:1",
        "5b28b203943ee73282028309:1",
        "5b28b203943ee73282028307:1",
        "5b28b203943ee732820282f5:1",
        "5b28b202943ee732820282f3:1"
    ],
    "workOrderIds": [
        1
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to search on objectId and use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId;